# Why can't I send formatted html files with my HTTP server

Tags: c++, sockets, http, server

I have a http server written in C which I plan to use for processing all requests in an ios app I'm building. When opening a html file with `fopen()` that is formatted for readability for example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get a blank web page. However, if I write everything on one line it works fine.
For example:

```
<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>
```

I was thinking that maybe I should remove all the white space before trying to send the file but then I would have to account for leaving the spaces between words and tag attributes.

I'm unsure of the proper way to send html files with return characters at the end of each line. Can someone explain why I'm getting a blank web page?

Here is my basic http server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DEFAULT_PORT 3015
#define IP "198.58.105.140"

int main()
{
        FILE *html_data;
        html_data = fopen("index.html", "r");

        char response_data[1024];
        fgets(response_data, 1024, html_data);

        char http_header[2048] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\n";
        strcat(http_header, response_data);

        struct sockaddr_in addr;
        unsigned int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_port = htons(DEFAULT_PORT);
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //inet_pton(AF_INET, IP, &(addr.sin_addr));

        int socketListener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        bind(socketListener, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, addrlen);
        listen(socketListener, SOMAXCONN);

        int newConnection;
        while(1)
        {
                newConnection = accept(socketListener, NULL, NULL);
                send(newConnection, http_header, sizeof(http_header), 0);
                //close(newConnection);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't C if it compiles; iostreams is part of C++ only.

Comment: This isn't a problem with the sending of the file, but with reading it in. The `fgets` function reads only until newline. You might want to used [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fread) instead. But my real recommendation is to not write your own web server if you're doing this for more than a toy project or school assignment; there are already many webservers already written and you'll probably have better luck using one of those.

Comment: @DanielH I know iostream is part of c++ but I only include it to output the message which I will be deleting. I'm still compiling with g++ though because as I build the server I will be using C++ function calls for integrating with MySQL and other things like business logic. I'm trying to write my own because I wan't to make a startup company that has it's own code base. You know a company like google doesn't use Apache2 or NGINX to host websites.

Comment: A company like Google isn't a startup, and they are focused on the web specifically. I'm pretty sure Stack Overflow uses IIS, [Wikipedia uses Apache](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikimedia_servers#Software), etc. Unless you specifically need features of a server which aren't provided by Apache, NGINX, etc., you shouldn't write your own. You can always do it later when there's a real business need, but even then it might be better to fork an existing one.

Comment: Your code does not actually *send* the contents.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That's what `send(newConnection, http_header, sizeof(http_header), 0);` does. Remember, he concatenated the contents to `http_header`.

Comment: It's a social media app and eventually I will be handling lots of data. I just figured that if I wanted everything to run as fast as possible, C/C++ would be the way to do it. In the startup stage I know it's not as important but as the application scales I will thank my self later that I don't have to do any rewrites. I may change my mind If C++ doesn't work for me, but I'm giving it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets()` just reads one line from the file. That's why your server works when the file has everything on one line. When you spread it over multiple lines, you only send the first line, which is just `<html>`, so there's nothing for the browser to display.

Use `fread()` to read more:

```
int size = fread(response_data, sizeof response_data - 1, 1, html_data);
response_data[size] = 0; // Add null terminator to string
```

And when you send the data, you shouldn't send past the null terminator. Use `strlen()` rather than `sizeof()` to get the number of valid characters.

```
send(newConnection, http_header, strlen(http_header), 0);
```